# MySQL SSL connection process

Tags: mysql, openssl

When you connect to MySQL through an SSL connection why do you pass the *server side certificates* as the parameters? I would have thought that (like with HTTPS) you would have a client side key and then do all the SSL handshakey stuff from there. But when you connect to MySQL with SSL you use:

```
mysql --ssl-ca=ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-key.pem
```

But the client key is coming from the server but I would have thought it came from the *client*?

It then leads onto the question about REQUIRE ISSUER (for example). Surely you only have a choice of using the same certificate the server issues so why would you ever need that parameter?

"If the client presents a certificate that is valid but has a different issuer"

How would the client ever present a certificate that was different?

Maybe I'm missing something obvious so apologies if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Err, what exactly are you talking about? The parameters you've shown are lkient certificates and keys, according to their names.

Comment: Not if you follow the tutorial which creates the keys on the *server* and never says to copy them across.

Answer (score -1):

The key here is that the client certificates must be manually copied to the client and used in the connection process. I hope that helps anyone else who didn't find this!

Comment: Eh? Client certificate are already *at* the client. None of this makes any sense.